# How to run AngularJS example

Tags: angularjs

I've done as described here: http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00 but can't run the phonecat example as AngularJS. It runs like a bunch of html files. For example, the app/index-async.html page gives me following error in Chrome's console:

```
Uncaught Error: No module: myApp
```

This file contains

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
```

Comment: What exactly have u done? I just cloned the git repo somewhere in my apaches htdocs and set it to stepp 00 and everything works fine for me.

Comment: tell me how to run a basic example.. i mean in what environment it should run.. i am just writing it as simple html and running. the concept of angular is very nice and i got it very quickly but none of tutorial said on how to execute it and environment setup :(

Answer (score 3):

The bootstrap part needs to be called after the element you're bootstrapping to is loaded. You can either put the bootstrap code at the end of your html, or you can use something like document ready from JQuery.

Comment: Adding `angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);` to the end of the HTML template worked for me, but putting _that_ inside jQuery's `$(document).ready()` did _not_ work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. When loading angular with reguirejs, **you have to remove the ng-app directive from the html** and add it after calling `angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp'])` like this:

`$(html).addClass('ng-app');`

Check this seed project out: https://github.com/tnajdek/angular-requirejs-seed specifically index.html and app/js/main.js

Answer (score -3):

Make sure your web server is running.

If you are running node.js:
1.  Run `node scripts\web-server.js` to start the web server
2.  In your browser, navigate to `http://localhost:8000/app/index.html`

If you are running some other http server:  (I used WAMP for the AngularJS tutorial you listed):
1.  Make sure the /angular-phonecat repository was cloned into your wamp/www folder.
2.  Navigate in your browser to http://localhost:[port-number]/angular-phonecat/app.

**TIPS:**
To change directories using WINDOWS COMMAND LINE -

```
cd /d c:\wamp\www
```

To change directories using GIT BASH -

```
$ cd /c/wamp/www
```

**Additional note:**  In Git Bash, to display the directory you're currently in, use `$ pwd`