# Angular JS auto-bootstrapping and manual bootstrapping failing for module

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

My module is defined as follows:

```
//controller.js
var app;

app = angular.module('toDoApp', []);

app.controller('toDoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.appTitle = 'ToDo List App';
  $scope.toDoText = '';

});
```

And I have tried bootstrapping my module in two ways, the first was automatically:

```
<html ng-app ="toDoApp" ng-controller="toDoCtrl">

<script src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js" </script>
<script src="controller.js" </script>
...
</html>
```

The second way I tried to was to manually bootstrap it:

```
<html>

<script src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js" </script>
<script src="controller.js" </script>
<script>angular.bootstrap(document, ['toDoApp']);</script>
...
</html>
```

The error I receive is:  [13:40:28.640] Error: No module: toDoApp @ https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js:18

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531197/how-to-run-angularjs-example) but it did not solve my issue.  I am also running it on a local server using node.js (which i don't think is the problem...)

```
    // server.js
var express  = require('express');
var app = express();                        // create our app w/ express
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;    

// config
app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));         
});


// listen (start todoapp with server.js) 
app.listen(port, function() {
console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working version:  http://plnkr.co/edit/pIjTH94lwl6ZZv48a2Xs?p=preview

The only change was to make sure the document was ready:

```
<script>
   angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['toDoApp']);
   });
<script>
```

[docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)

Comment: would this be in my html file or my controller.js file?

Comment: Just replace `<script>angular.bootstrap(document, ['toDoApp']);</script>` in your .html with the above

Comment: [14:10:16.034] Use of attributes' specified attribute is deprecated. It always returns true. @ https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js:41  error in the jquery?